# Python - find minimum value greater than 0 in a list of instances

Tags: python

I have a list of instances (of `Process` class) named `process_list`. I'm strugling to find min value of attribute `l_time` greater than 0.
This is how my class looks:

```
class Process:

    def __init__(self, id, a_time, p_time):
        self.id = id
        self.a_time = a_time
        self.p_time = p_time
        self.l_time = p_time
        self.w_time = 0
        self.ta_time = 0
        self.is_available = False
```

I tried something like:

```
current_process = min(i for i in process_list if i.l_time > 0)
```

it gives an error :

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Process' and 'Process'

Do I have to write a `__gt__`function somehow or is there a way to do it using `lambda`?

Comment: You can pass a `key` function to `min` (often a lambda) that will function as though you had defined a `__gt__`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort for details on `key` (sort, min and max all use it the same way).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the key parameter of min:

```
class Process:

    def __init__(self, id, a_time, p_time):
        self.id = id
        self.a_time = a_time
        self.p_time = p_time
        self.l_time = p_time
        self.w_time = 0
        self.ta_time = 0
        self.is_available = False

process_list = [Process(1, 10, 10), Process(1, 5, 5), Process(1, -5, -5)]
result = min((p for p in process_list if p.l_time > 0), key= lambda x: x.l_time)

print(result.l_time)
```

**Output**

```
5
```